# Using a third table to define my selection

Tags: sql, oracle11g

As you can see in the picture, one student can attend many classes. Many classes can attend many events.

I am trying to write a select statement that selects students that are apart of a class that attends a specific event.

I've tried using:

```
select students.student_id
from students
left join student_class
on students.student_id = student_class.student_id
where student_class.class_id = event.event_id
and student_class.class_id = event.class_id;
```

To no avail.
I'm talking about the tables in this picture below;

[image]

Comment: You've missed the join to `event`. If you read the error message you get when you try running that statement, you could perhaps learn how to diagnose these sorts of things for yourself :)

Comment: @JeffreyKemp I was thinking that the `where student_class.class_id = event.event_id` qualified as a join.

Comment: `event.event_id` is a reference to a column, but you have not defined what `event` is. There is nothing in your `from` clause that defines what `event` is.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp I got it!

Comment: Well done, you've started on a wonderful road of discovery of the power of SQL :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

```
select students.*
from students
join student_class
on students.student_id = student_class.student_id
where
    (select distinct event.class_id 
    from event
    inner join student_class
    on student_class.class_id = event.class_id
    where upper(event.event_name) = 'GUEST SPEAKER'
    ) = student_class.class_id;
```

I had to work on it like a chain starting with an `inner join` between `students` and `students_class`. I then used the output from a sub select in the `where` clause to define my final output in the outer select.

Comment: Good work. You could make this even simpler by removing the redundant join to `student_class`; I'll add this as an answer (but you don't have to accept it, it's just for your interest).

Comment: Note that the default type of join is inner, so `inner join` is equivalent to `join`.

Answer (score 0):

Just for interest, here's one way you can remove the redundant join to `student_class`. You can use a correlated `where exists` clause:

```
select students.*
from students
where exists (
  select null
  from student_class
  join event
  on event.event_id = student_class.event_id
  where students.student_id = student_class.student_id
  and upper(event.event_name) = 'GUEST SPEAKER'
  );
```